# How do I make a local branch track another local branch at a particular commit id?

Tags: git

How do I make a local branch track another local branch at a particular commit id?

Suppose I have a local branch branch1 with the following commits,

```
commit1
commit2
commit3
```

Can I create another local branch branch2 that tracks branch1 starting at commit2?

```
commit1
commit2 <- HEAD of branch2
commit3 <- HEAD of branch1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
git branch branch2 commit2
```

creates a branch `branch2` pointing to `commit2`. It hardly could be named "tracked" because it just points to the commit and nothing else.

If you want to switch to that branch and add commits don't forget to `git checkout branch2`.